# Вопросы по библиотеке highcharts для построения графиков

Tags: javascript, график, highcharts

1. В библиотеке есть ссылки на файлы, которые лежат в папке core. Например: Core/Globals.js или Core/Utilities.js. Никак не могу их найти. Где они находятся?
2. Библиотека записана в строку без отступов и перевода строки. Если программы чтобы привести код в читабельный вид?
3. Объясните что за функция такая (function(W,M){.....}). С нее начинается библиотека.
4. После этого идет строка в виде (this,function(W){....}). Почему тут стоит this? Я понимаю что это относится к объектам, но почему он идет в самом начале и через запятую следует функция?
5. В оставшейся части кода последовательно вызываются функции М. Например:
   M(
   d,"Core/Utilities.js",[d["Core/Globals.js"]],
   function(c){}).
   Как понять эти функции.
   [jsfiddle](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/dynamic-update)

Comment: Так на гитхабе исходники есть https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/ts

Comment: А вы пытаетесь смотреть сжатый скомпилированный забандленный код, в этом нет никакого смысла, он не предназначен для чтения людьми